# React SPA with OIDC PKCE and identityserver.io

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, identityserver4, openid-connect, pkce

As a school assignment I have to make the following:

## Overview

Create a React SPA which does the following:

1. Authenticates against ([Welcome to the IdentityServer4 demo site](https://demo.identityserver.io/)) using the authorization code flow with PKCE
2. Calls ([test](https://demo.identityserver.io/api/test)) using the correct token

## Detail

Create a SPA in **React**. Usage of React is mandatory this time.

- add a library which adds OIDC protocol support to the SPA. **Make sure the authorization code flow with PKCE is supported**
- use  ([Welcome to the IdentityServer4 demo site](https://demo.identityserver.io/))as your authorization server. This authorization server supports the authorization code flow with PKCE
- call ([test](https://demo.identityserver.io/api/test)) using the correct token and show the results back to the user
- host the react app on Netlify

As a beginner in this field, I totally don’t understand the assignment. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you be more clear on which parts you don't understand? I.e., are you comfortable making a React SPA yet, etc.

Comment: I could hardly believe this would be a school assignment...

Comment: I made a simple react application. So with the standard demo page... for the rest I don’t have alot of knowledge about SPA, OIDC and PKCE in connection with identiityserver.io

Comment: Haha you can try and tell my teacher...

Comment: Which school is that? Sounds pretty cool.

Comment: College in Belgium mate

Answer (score 18):

In the interest of being nice, here are some pointers and a solution to your assignment. But please, please, please - don't just copy it, learn how it works, think it through, apply it to your own react app.

First of all, while identityserver has very good documentation at https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/ - it is very code-oriented and might be hard to start with.

So instead, take a look aut Auth0, a competing commercial product. They have pretty good docs as well, and they explain some of the protocols too.
https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2
https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code-pkce
These are of particular interest.

Now, they also have scenarios like the one you need to implement. You might think it's this one: https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api but they are a little behind in the new guidelines (but luckily your assignment isn't) that SPA's should also use code flow with PKCE, so you're better off with this: https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/mobile-api
(more on why this is better here: https://brockallen.com/2019/01/03/the-state-of-the-implicit-flow-in-oauth2/)

Having read all that, you need to find a good JS library that does oidc/oauth for you. No use in writing one yourself in school unless you're going for a Phd.

Google javascript oidc -> https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js comes up. Hey! It's those guys from identityserver again. They're great people, aren't they? They've certainly got your back.

Now google react oidc-client-js - well isn't that nice, someone beat you to it: https://github.com/skoruba/react-oidc-client-js